# Why is there a 2 in front of some of these passive component parts?

Tags: schematic

Why is there a 2 in front of some of these passive component parts?

[image]

Comment: Note that in some applications, the actual values of resistor/resistor pairs may not be critical, but their ratios is.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, \$R_B\$ is defined as 1 MΩ and so \$2R_B\$ is 2 MΩ: -

[image]

Comment: Presumably it's done as \$2R_B\$, rather than \$R_C\$ with \$R_C=2MΩ\$ because the fact that one is twice the other is more important than the absolute value? Is there an obvious reason why there "seems" (from symmetry, if nothing else) to be a "missing" \$R_B\$ in the lower half?

Comment: @TripeHound yes, the lower resistor network is asymmetrical so that if the thermocouple became disconnected or broken, there is a means by which the monitoring circuit can detect this situation.

Answer (score 11):

It means whatever value you choose for \$R_\mathrm B\$, use \$2\times R_\mathrm B\$ at that position. Eg \$R_\mathrm B\$ is \$1\ \mathrm{M\Omega}\$, \$2R_\mathrm B\$ is \$2\ \mathrm{M\Omega}\$.

Answer (score 7):

It means that the 2R<sub>A</sub> resistor values are twice those of the R<sub>A</sub> values and similarly with the R<sub>B</sub> values.

If R<sub>A</sub> is 1 kΩ then the 2R<sub>A</sub> value is 2 kΩ.